# Map List<object> to List<EmployeeDC> in MVC#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

EmployeeDC is having following properties - `EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EmployeeLocation`. From Database List is returning. How to map this to List using Automapper or any other mechanism in MVC3?

Comment: Do you have an example of the structure of what you want to map from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example AutoMapper configuration:

See [Custom Type Converters](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters).

```
public class EmployeeDC
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeLocation { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeConverter : ITypeConverter<object, EmployeeDC>
{
    public EmployeeDC Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var model = context.SourceValue;

        var employeeId = ???;
        var employeeName = ???;
        var employeeLocation = ???;

        return new EmployeeDC
                   {
                       EmployeeId = employeeId,
                       EmployeeName = employeeName,
                       EmployeeLocation = employeeLocation
                   };
    }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<object, EmployeeDC>()
      .ConvertUsing<EmployeeConverter>();
```

Comment: do i need to add reference for ITypeConverter and ResolutionContext? If yes, can u please assist me with the refernce?

Answer (score 0):

I have used both automapper an value injector. i found Value injector is better than auto mapper.

below is the project home page

http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/

Detail example about to map see the below link.
http://sampathloku.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/how-to-use-valueinjecter-with-aspnet.html